# how to edit Synaptics Capabilities , right touchpad button is not working

Tags: touchpad, synaptics, xinput

Can you help me enable my right click button of my touchpad? Please, find out my Synaptics Capabilities.

I am using Ubuntu 16.04

```
xinput list-props "SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad" | grep Capabilities
```

Synaptics Capabilities (300):  1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1